# Duplicate additional participant created during online payment(event)

Tags: civievent

In online event registration, duplicate additional  participant created  when user click continue button on review page after come back from Payment gateway(PG like Paypal Standard, Monerise) by clicking browser back button.

Civicrm version: 4.6.2

Any fix?

Thanks,
Siv

Answer (score 0):

If the payment was successfully then the user has to be redirected to thank you page -

I guess you are speaking about - 
user manually clicking the back button or cancel button before successful payment - in that case you need to redirect the page to the event start page or just refresh the page again

This is an cache issue

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: Page will be redirected to start page if the user click cancel button in payment page but issue only when user click back button in payment page.You can try this steps,
1. Start page
2. Additional participant page
2. Review page(Participant record will be created when you click continue button)
3. Payment page(don't fill anything and just click browser back button then the review page will be displayed)
4. Now click the continue button in review page. Now additional participant created again.

I don't think this is cache issue.

Comment: please provide me a public link for testing - thanks

Comment: In civicrm demo site itself you can see that issue,
http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/register?reset=1&action=preview&id=1

Comment: You got a chance to check this?

Comment: Hi I am working on the same with payment processor will let you know once done - Thanks

Comment: Hi - This is not cache issue but still this has nothing to do with civicrm as this is an human issue - If a user is clicking the back button on the browser then I suggest notify the user to not do so - that might help else if you think of fixing the issue then please refer to the below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926641/how-to-disable-back-button-in-browser-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I hope we can do something with civicrm to fix this issue as this issue only with additional participant not with primary participant. Fixing the issue in civicrm is necessary i think even if we can do javascript to disable back button. I will update if i find fix for this.